# PowerBI Filter Not Displaying Correct Values

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a rather vexing situation in PowerBI. I developed a rank for my company's employees based on minimal time it takes them to do something. It's a ranking based on three separate factors; to do this, 'rank' had to be a measure.

So, I have a measure 'rank' which works as I intend it to:

```
Rank = IF ( HASONEVALUE( Query1[Employee Name] ), RANKX( ALLSELECTED ( Query1[Employee Name] ), [Rank_Total],, TRUE) )
```

where `[Rank_Total]` is the measure that creates a raw score of the three separate factors I mentioned earlier. So, `[Rank_Total]` creates a raw score, and `[Rank]` orders the raw values in `[Rank_Total]`.

Here's where things get weird: if I want to simply choose the top 5 entries based on `[Rank]`, I get *nothing*.

Here's what I mean: I created a measure called `Test Measure`, and I set it to:

```
Test Measure = IF( [Rank] < 6, 1, 0 )
```

This updated the matrix appropriately:

[image]

However, when I filter "Test Measure" to only include the "1's," this happens:

[image]

Does anyone have a suggestion as to why this is happening, and what an appropriate workaround is?

**EDITED TO ADD:**
[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dKF1qKsM3mmCXRWRo_ujLz4eLl58S9waxW5HEdSErZw/edit?usp=sharing) is a link to a Google public sheet for example data.
The parameters I have are as follows:

`Loan Count = COUNT(Query1[Loan Number])`

`Loan Count by Employee = Loan Count by Employee = CALCULATE([Loan Count], GROUPBY(Query1, Query1[Employee Name]))`

`Volume = Sum(Query1[Loan Amount])`

`Avg CTC Time = AVERAGE(Query1[CTC Time])`

`Avg CTC Time by Employee = CALCULATE([Avg CTC Time], GROUPBY(Query1, Query1[Employee Name]))`

Now, for the Ranks. The Rank I have to based on three separate factors, in the following order:

1. Lowest CTC Time
2. Highest Loan Count
3. Highest Volume

Here are the measures:

`Rank_CTCLength = IF ( HASONEVALUE( Query1[Employee Name] ), RANKX( ALLSELECTED ( Query1[Employee Name] ), [Avg CTC Time by Employee],, TRUE) )`

`Rank_LoanCount = IF ( HASONEVALUE( Query1[Employee Name] ), RANKX( ALLSELECTED ( Query1[Employee Name] ), [Loan Count] ,, False) )`

`Rank_LoanVolume = IF ( HASONEVALUE( Query1[Employee Name] ), RANKX( ALLSELECTED ( Query1[Employee Name] ), [Volume],, False) )`

I factored all three of them to make a "raw score" titled "Rank_Total":

`Rank_Total = FORMAT([Rank_CTCLength]+[Rank_LoanCount]*POWER(10,-4)+[Rank_LoanVolume]*POWER(10,-8),"00000.00000000%")`

From there, I created the final rank parameter titled `Rank`:

`Rank = IF ( HASONEVALUE( Query1[Employee Name] ), RANKX( ALLSELECTED ( Query1[Employee Name] ), [Rank_Total],, TRUE) )`

Answer (score 1):

With limited information, I think the reason why this happens is because when you apply a filter based on a measure (in this case `Test Measure`), it changes the data available in the visual and causes Power BI to reevaluate the other measures (e.g. `Rank`) based on the new data set.

Instead of creating a new measure for filtering purpose, my suggestion is to apply a `Top N Filter` on an existing `column` in the visual (e.g. `EmployeeID`), based on the `measure` (`Rank`).

Example and result:
[image: result]

---

**EDIT:**

First of all, some suggestions. I noticed that you've created `Avg CTC Time by Employee` and `Loan Count by Employee` besides `Avg CTC Time` and `Loan Count`. This is actually not needed because the beauty of `Measure` in Power BI is that it will be evaluated based on current data context. Therefore, when you add `Avg CTC Time` measure next to `Employee Name` column in a matrix, it'll be evaluated as Avg CTC Time by employee automatically. (see screenshot below, same value for the two columns)

[image: same result]

I really appreciate the extra information you've provided in tackling this problem. Unfortunately, the data set is still not enough to reproduce the issue. It even works perfectly for the `Test Measure` you suggested failing in the question. Therefore I'm afraid you have to cross-compare with your original query and add more details to a point where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding. Unfortunately, after following the steps you listed, my chart just goes blank- no rows show up at all.

Comment: @daOnlyBG Can you share more like a sample set of the data and the data model so we can pinpoint the specific challenge in this case?

Comment: Certainly. Let me put something together really quickly. What's the best way to upload a small sample set of data onto this page?

Comment: I think copying it to a public Google Sheet can do.

Comment: I have the pertinent info updated in my question on the bottom- thanks!

Comment: I don't know if this helps or not, but if I were to filter a "Top N" according to 'Loan Count' or 'Volume,' I get only the top 5 displayed- and it's nice. However, I need it to be by `Average CTC Time`, and that one simply returns blank space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139389/discussion-between-daonlybg-and-foxan-ng).